# Vs2010 Proxy, where's the code

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have inhherited a vs2010 c# web project (asp.net). It has a web reference to a web service. There's been a slight change to the service - a new operation has been added. I'd like to update the proxy class so that i can call the new operation but i can't find the class. I seem to remember there used to be a "show all files" button in solution explorer that would reveal the proxy class but i can see no sign of that. Unfortunately, i'm not able to refresh the proxy by pointing it at the web service metadata wsdl because vs is no longer installed on any pc that can reach the web service. Anyone know where i can find the proxy class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was, the app was running - doh!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter you can't find it in Visual Studio - you can always locate a proper file in your filesystem, under the project directory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. There is a "Show all files" icon in the tool bar. It will only be available when you have a *project* selected, so you want to select the web service's parent project:

[image: show all files]

Expand the service reference and under it the file called Reference.cs is the proxy class.

[image: Reference.cs]

You should **NOT** be hand editing this though. You should make the changes to the service and then regenerate the proxy using the `Update Service Reference` right click option. But then if you **really** can't do that as you say, then just hand edit the file. But beware that any changes you make will be lost if someone does regenerate it again in the future. **Very Risky**! (I prey you are using source control)

[image: Update Service Reference]

Answer (score 0):

There is a WSDL.exe command line tool.

Copy and execute this command line tool in the PC where you can have access to the WebService, it will generates the proxy again and you can replace them with the files in your project.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(v=vs.80).aspx